# Simple ,fast script support for a c# application

Tags: c#, scripting

I have developed an application which can create Xml files from Xml schema with some user defined rules for generating value for each node.

I want to give my user the ability to write scripts for generating value for each node and in this scripts user should be able to refer to generated value of other nodes .
a simple script will be something like :

```
returtn (@node1.value + 10) ;
```

I don't know what will be the value of @node1.value because the file generation process hasn't started yet.

so what is the solution do I have to replace it every time with the generated value and then run the script or is there a better way to do something like this ?

may be I have to run this script thousand of times to generate value for created instances so which scripting language is the fastest one for me to use ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).
If you are looking for a script language with a sysntax similar to C#, then you can look at [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/).

Comment: I don't know about the speed and couldn't find any test comparing IronPython and CS-Script but have selected using CS-Script just because it's syntax is easier for my users .
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using C# as your scripting language?

http://www.csscript.net/

Answer (score 0):

Use locks :-). If someone invokes get_method of the property that isn't set just lock the caller until value is set.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell embeds well into a C# application, here's how from the [PowerShell Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583250.aspx)